# Spawning large numbers of WebWorkers in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, canvas, web-worker

I'm writing a simple JavaScript application that generates a [Mandlebrot set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) fractal in an HTML5 `canvas` element.  The algorithm to generate the graphic is easily parallelizable, so I'm using WebWorkers to cut the screen up into more manageable chunks.  I'm running into some issues when I spawn large numbers of WebWorkers, though, and it seems to be browser specific:

**Chrome:** Generating between 32 and 64 WebWorkers kills the page.  The strange part is the WebWorkers don't seem to be being destroyed once they finish executing.  For example, if I run the simulation once with 32 WebWorkers, I have no problems, but if I re-run the simulation (without reloading the page), the page dies.

**Firefox:** It seems that Firefox just gives up after spawning a certain number of WebWorkers, and it's less than 32.  A set number of the WebWorkers finish, and the rest seem to exist in some limbo state, never finishing execution.  I don't get any ouput in Firebug's error console.

**Safari:** Safari is the only browser that seems to flawlessly spawn large numbers of WebWorkers.  No problems here.

**IE:** Who cares?

Does anyone have a solution to any of these browser-specific issues, or at least know what's causing these problems?

Comment: Workers (as these background scripts are called herein) are relatively heavy-weight, and are not intended to be used in large numbers. -> [source](http://dev.w3.org/html5/workers/#scope)

Comment: It would seem as if different browsers reach different limits as you seem to have found out. [Relevant question here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339892/does-a-firefox-workers-limit-exist)

Comment: Can you link to your page?  It sounds like your workers aren't terminating or something.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have `worker.terminate();` statements to shut down the workers when they're done? This can definitely be a blocker.