# Web Worker threads randomly hanging in Firefox

Tags: javascript, multithreading, google-chrome, firefox, web-worker

I am having issues with web worker threads hanging randomly. This is only happening in Firefox (on version 32.0.3). I have a button that when clicked fetches a large list from my API and sorts it via a threaded mergesort implemented in web workers using a threadpool via [threadpool.js](https://github.com/andywer/threadpool-js). The entire system works extremely well in Chrome, but 1 out of maybe every 10 executions hangs in Firefox. If I click the button to cause another fetch/sort to happen while the previous one is hung (each execution creates a new threadpool and therefore new workers), it will then come back to life and finish executing. What is even more interesting, is that I can run a log command as the first line in the function that is  executed as the worker when the hang happens and I do not get execution of that line until after it has been "woken up" like I described above.

Does anyone have any insight into why this may be happening or some suggestions on tracking it down? I have tried this with and without firebug enabled (since newer versions of firebug hijack some web worker code allowing for console output) in case there was an error on their end, but I get the same results either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, every data fetch I was creating a new threadpool to handle the sorting of my data. The threadpool.js library does not have any cleanup code (until I added it, I'll make a pull request soon enough). So if the past call's threadpool had not yet been garbage collected, I would see the error when I would hit firefox's web worker thread limit. Details on the worker limit are below:

[Does a Firefox Workers limit exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339892/does-a-firefox-workers-limit-exist)